# What language is this?

Tags: programming-languages

The language in which you define every function and everything as whatever you like. So basically you can program in poetry if you wanted.

Comment: The wonderful world of pseudo code and the nightmare of compiler writers?

Comment: This question doesn't make a lot of sense unless you describe the context: where did you hear about such a thing?

Comment: I think you may have gotten hold of an unduly simplified description...and it doesn't leave much for us to work with. Can you be a little more specific--more detail or more context?

Comment: I don't remember. I'm just hoping someone remembers it.

Comment: "When someone says \"I want a programming language in which I need only say what I wish done,\" give him a lollipop." -- Alan Perlis

Comment: Well Perl can be written in poetry form, but that is not what you mean: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Perl

Comment: Sounds like VPL - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb483088.aspx

Comment: Sad that this is closed. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literate_programming or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forth_%28programming_language%29

Comment: @Moontear, yeah, sad it's already closed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is vague, but you might be thinking of Forth.

Comment: I believe this is what I was looking for.

Comment: Also, vague questions based on memories of half-heard sentences is my speciatly.

Comment: @Port: That is not something to brag about.

Answer (score 0):

English, or pick your native tongue.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments, sounds like pseudo code. This question really needs a lot more description and maybe an example for people to see.